# Ordering a list of dataframes by minimum column value in R

Tags: r, glm

As a preliminary to creating a multivariate logistic regression I'm doing univariate regressions and want to select the variables with p < 0.20 to include in the multivariate model. I can map the required variables to `glm` and get the output of the models, but am struggling to order them by rank of p-value.

This is what I have so far:

```
predictor1 <- c(0,1.1,2.4,3.1,4.0,5.9,4.2,3.3,2.2,1.1)
predictor2 <- as.factor(c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no"))
predictor3 <- as.factor(c("a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "c", "a", "a", "a", "c"))
outcome <- as.factor(c("alive","dead","alive","dead","alive","dead","alive","dead","alive","dead"))
df <- data.frame(pred1 = predictor1, pred2 = predictor2, pred3 = predictor3, outcome = outcome)
predictors <- c("pred1", "pred2", "pred3")
df %>%
    select(predictors) %>%
    map(~ glm(df$outcome ~ .x, data = df, family = "binomial"))  %>%
    #Extract odds ratio, confidence interval lower and upper bounds, and p value
    map(function (x, y) data.frame(OR = exp(coef(x)), 
        lower=exp(confint(x)[,1]), 
        upper=exp(confint(x)[,2]),
        Pval = coef(summary(x))[,4]))
```

This code spits out a summary of each model

```
$pred1
                OR   lower          upper           Pval
    (Intercept) 0.711082 0.04841674 8.521697    0.7818212
    .x          1.133085 0.52179227 2.653040    0.7465663
$pred2
                OR   lower          upper           Pval
    (Intercept) 1   0.18507173  5.40331     1
    .xyes   1   0.07220425  13.84960    1
$pred3
                OR   lower          upper           Pval
    (Intercept) 0.25    0.0127798   1.689944    0.2149978
    .xb         170179249.43 0.0000000  NA  0.9961777
    .xc         12.00   0.6908931   542.678010  0.1220957
```

but with my real dataset there are dozens of predictors so I need a way to order the output. Preferably by the minimum (non-intercept) p-value in each model. Maybe the data structure I've chosen for the summary of each model isn't the best, so any suggestions on how to get the same information in a more flexible data structure would be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map_dfr` instead of `map`, filter rows with intercept then do `arrange`. Use `tidy` from `broom` instead of your custom function.

```
library(broom)    
df %>%
   select(predictors) %>%
   map(~ glm(df$outcome ~ .x, data = df, family = "binomial")) %>%
   map_dfr(tidy, .id='Model') %>% 
   filter(term!="(Intercept)") %>% arrange(p.value)

# A tibble: 4 x 6
Model term   estimate std.error statistic p.value
<chr> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 pred3 .xc    2.48e+ 0     1.61   1.55e+ 0   0.122
2 pred1 .x     1.25e- 1     0.387  3.23e- 1   0.747
3 pred3 .xb    1.90e+ 1  3956.     4.79e- 3   0.996
4 pred2 .xyes -5.73e-16     1.29  -4.44e-16   1.000
```

Comment: The `tidy` function is just what I was looking for. It gives the info I need in a handy format that includes the model and term. Thanks.

Comment: @pgcudahy you're most welcome, have a look at _broom_, it has many other useful functions e.g `glance`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `do.call(rbind)` approach, then order by p-value. The `[-1, ]` omits the intercepts.

```
pl <- do.call(rbind, sapply(predictors, function(x) {
  fo <- reformulate(x, response="outcome")
  summary(glm(fo, data=df, family="binomial"))$coef[-1, ]
  }))
pl[order(pl[, 4]), ]
#             Estimate   Std. Error       z value  Pr(>|z|)
# pred3c  2.484907e+00    1.6072751  1.546037e+00 0.1220957
# pred1   1.249440e-01    0.3866195  3.231703e-01 0.7465663
# pred3b  1.895236e+01 3956.1804861  4.790571e-03 0.9961777
# pred2  -5.733167e-16    1.2909944 -4.440892e-16 1.0000000
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(pred1 = c(0, 1.1, 2.4, 3.1, 4, 5.9, 4.2, 3.3, 
2.2, 1.1), pred2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), pred3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"
), class = "factor"), outcome = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("alive", "dead"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

predictors <- c("pred1", "pred2", "pred3")
```